# SQLAlchemy ORM join along relationship path in recursive CTE

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm constructing a recursive query on a self-referencing table using SQLAlchemy 2.0.

What is the correct way to perform a join along a relationship path in the recursive part of a CTE?

This is the model I'm working with

```py
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), unique=True)
    parent_id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("tags.id"))

    parent: Mapped[Optional["Tag"]] = relationship(back_populates="children", remote_side=[id])
    children: Mapped[list["Tag"]] = relationship(back_populates="parent")
```

Following the example in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.HasCTE.cte), the following explicit join works

```py
rec_base = select(Tag).where(Tag.name == "search").cte(name="rec_tags", recursive=True)
parent = aliased(rec_base, name="parent")
rec_tags = rec_base.union_all(select(Tag).join(parent, Tag.parent_id == parent.c.id))
```

If I use the `relationship` to automatically determine the ON clause, like so:

```py
rec_tags = rec_base.union_all(select(Tag).join(parent, Tag.parent))
```

It produces the same sql, but gives a warning:

> SADeprecationWarning: An alias is being generated automatically against joined entity Mapper[Tag(tags)] for raw clauseelement, which is deprecated and will be removed in a later release. Use the aliased() construct explicitly, see the linked example. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xaj1)

The linked docs state the preferred way to do this would be by using an alias that references the mapped class.

If I understand correctly, that looks like this

```py
parent = aliased(Tag, rec_base, name="parent")
rec_tags = rec_base.union_all(select(Tag).join(Tag.parent.of_type(parent)))
```

However, that fails with

> CompileError: Multiple, unrelated CTEs found with the same name: 'rec_tags'

Am I missing something, or is this a limitation of the API?